# Qt application is not installed on other system, except the system where build was made

Tags: qt5

I have made an application using Qt 5.0.2 and made its build using inno setup. The application is successfully installed and launched at my system and worked fine.But when i installed it on other system, application is not installing or launching also no error showing. Please help me guys... What to do

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio to build your application you will probably need to install vcredist_sp1_x86.exe on the destination machine. You can find it somewhere in the installation folder of Qt. You can add it to the list of files in the Inno script, and add entry in the [Run] section. Also make sure you have included in your setup script:

```
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
libGLESv2.dll
icuuc49.dll
icuin49.dll
icudt49.dll
D3DCompiler_43.dll
plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll ->should be installed in platforms/qwindows.dll in the destination folder. The same applies to imageformats plugins if you use them.
```

If you think there are too much dlls you will need to rebuild Qt with other configuration options, but that's another story...